# fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'FPDF error: Not a JPEG file

Tags: php, function, pdf, jpeg, fpdf

HERE IS THE CODE.line no 62
https://pastebin.com/wTgeJjNR

//$qus_img is empty

```
        $qus_imga = "data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($qus_img);

        $pic = getImage($qus_imga);


       function getImage($dataURI)
         {
                $img = explode(',',$dataURI,2);
                $pic = 'data://text/plain;base64,'.$img[1];
                $type = explode("/", explode(':', substr($dataURI, 0, 
                strpos($dataURI, ';')))[1])[1]; // get the image type
                if ($type=="png"||$type=="jpeg"||$type=="gif") return 
                array($pic, $type);
                return false;
         }
```

Comment: Please include enough of the code to reproduce the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: There is too much code in your pastebin to put here.  Please [edit] your question and post the minimum amount of code solve your problem.